# Reading excel columns with openpyxl in a similar way like in pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas, openpyxl

Disclaimer, unfortunately I cannot use `pandas` module.

I need to be able to read xls and xlsx files.

More specifically my current requirements are:

1.Being able to read each table's columns names simply.
2.Get all columns values in a list by a column name holding a list of values.

In `pandas` its so plain simple
Example for `1`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xls')
df.columns.values.tolist()
```

Example for `2`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xls')
df[col_name].values
```

Please advise how can I achieve the same using `openpyxl`, and if not possible maybe using other package similar to `pandas`.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells

Comment: @CharlieClark: Can you please advise regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337032/can-i-disable-openpyxl-from-automatically-parsing-strings-to-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the desired results.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb[SheetName]
```

Question 1):

```
[cell.value for cell in row if cell.value 
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_row=1)]

['foo',
'buzz',
'fizz']
```

How this works. We specify the column it is starting to look at is Column 1, specified by `min_col=1`. We specify the row it stops looking at as Row 1, specified by `max_row=1`. The `if` statement checks to see if the cell is empty upon which it doesn't return that value, that is there since we do not know the number of columns.

Question 2)

```
[cell.value for cell in row if cell.value 
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=2)]

['this',
'is',
'a',
'test']
```

The same logic applies here as well. We are binding the search to only the first column by using both `min_col` & `max_col` and setting both to 1. The minimum row is now row 2 meaning we skip the header and search all the way down column 1 until it returns nothing.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your reply, can you explain a bit how first code is returning only columns names- what's the logic behind?
And for the second question as well thanks

Comment: Updated with a brief explanation

Comment: What if the column headers not appear as first row ?

Comment: @JavaSa then you would modify accordingly based on where they do appear. I think it seems pretty straightforward how you would change the column and row parameters to capture the data you want.

Comment: Yes, but I though there is some algorithm to catch columns like in pandas, not something that I need to imlement.

Comment: Anyway there is a syntax error in the list comprehension, its not recognizing the row parameter