# Can I disable openpyxl from automatically parsing strings to datetime?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, openpyxl

I'm having simple excel files with various timstamp formats written as strings.
There is a build in feature in openpyxl to automatically convert what seems like a date to a datetime object.

My question is simple, how can I take the **raw** string as it was inserted to the excel file by the user, without intervention of `openpyxl`.

I want to do my own format testings using a function that tries various calls to `datetime.strptime` myself.

Loading the excel is done by me like this:

```
import openpyxl
ex = openpyxl.load_workbook('/path/to/file.xls')
worksheet = ex.active
```

In case needing to iterate over rows I'm using `worksheet.iter_rows` method

Answer (score 3):

You're assumption is incorrect: openpyxl does not convert strings unless you ask it to by setting `guess_types=True`. Excel treats the values as datetime objects by setting the number format and internally converting them to serials with an epoch of 1899-12-30.

Comment: I already tried guess_type=False, so I guess the excel converting the strings as you mentioned.
Any ideas how can I take the raw string wriiten by excell user?
If I convert to csv, also in csv dates are auto converting to datetime?

Comment: @JavaSa if it is returning python datetime object why cannot you just handle if `isinstance(cell.value, datetime.datetime)` and handle `if isinstance(cell.value, basestring)` separately in your own code?

Comment: `guess_types` is deprecated